# Android Google Analytics v3

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've upgraded analytics v2 to v3 but now I can't track information, if I go to google analytics page all statistics are empty. I'm doing really simple tracking:

**AnalyticsManager:**

```
private static final String APP_LIFECYCLE_CATEGORY = "Application - Android";
private static final String APP_OPEN = "Android - App Open";
private static final String APP_CLOSE = "Android - App Closed";

public static void setup(Context context) {
        gaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
        gaTracker = gaInstance.getTracker(C.isAnalyticsInQA() ? C.ANALYTICS_TEST_KEY : C.ANALYTICS_RELEASE_KEY);
        gaInstance.setDefaultTracker(gaTracker);
        gaInstance.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    }

    public static void tearDown() {
        gaInstance.closeTracker(gaTracker.getName());
    }

    public static void trackAppCloseEvent() {
        gaTracker.send(MapBuilder
          .createEvent(APP_LIFECYCLE_CATEGORY, APP_CLOSE, "", 0L)
          .set(Fields.SESSION_CONTROL, "start")
          .build());
    }

    public static void trackAppOpenEvent() {
        gaTracker.send(MapBuilder
          .createEvent(APP_LIFECYCLE_CATEGORY, APP_OPEN, "", 0L)
          .set(Fields.SESSION_CONTROL, "close")
          .build());
    }
```

**Application:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ...
    AnalyticsManager.setup(this);
    AnalyticsManager.trackAppOpenEvent();
}



@Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        AnalyticsManager.trackAppCloseEvent();
        AnalyticsManager.tearDown();
        ...
        super.onTerminate();
    }
```

Anyone with the same problem?
Btw, all google analytics dev guides are giving me HTTP 500 if I don't specify the query parameter "?hl=". Is this supposed to happen? I never had to specify it before...

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration?hl=en

Comment: Any reason for migrating to v3? I mean v4 is already available so I am asking. @GuilhE

Comment: Didn't know v4 was out. I was using v2 and I had to update because v2 doesn't work with API21

Comment: Check this out https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't knew v4 was already out as @Pooja mentioned. Migrated to v4 and it works perfectly.